# Is there a way to prevent jquery unobtrusive validation from setting the focus on the invalid field

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I have a jquery mobile page with a form with a few textboxes.  I'm using jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to validate the form. If a field is marked as required and the user doesn't fill it out validation catches it and places focus on the textbox. On a mobile device like iPhone and Android, that focus will scroll the screen and bring up the virtual keyboard, which sometimes hides the validation messaging or scrolls past it.  I curious if there is a way to disable this 'autofocus on invalidate' behavior.

It may not ultimately be the better user experience but I'd like to experiment with turning it off.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", onValidationHandler);
});

function onValidationHandler(form, validator) {
    validator.settings && (validator.settings.focusInvalid = false);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this the best when using unobtrusive validation. Just add this to your scripts, and it'll disable the auto-focus behaviour no matter how validation is ran:

```
$.validator.defaults.focusInvalid = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `focusInvalid` option to `false`:

```
$("#form").validate({
    focusInvalid: false
});
```

> Focus the last active or first invalid element on submit via validator.focusInvalid(). The last active element is the one that had focus when the form was submitted, avoiding to steal its focus. If there was no element focused, the first one in the form gets it, unless this option is turned off.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3JtBF/